# Autocomplete is not working

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I have a list with names and an AutoCompleteTextView. I need that AutoCompleteTextView to filter the names by the string the user enters, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong because AutoCompleteTextView will not work. Can you help me?

Here is my code:

```
cursor = socioData.getAllSocios();
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        cursor,
        new String[]{Socio.C_NOME},
        new int[]{android.R.id.text1}
        );

filterText = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.search);
filterText.setThreshold(1);
filterText.setAdapter(adapter);
adapter.setCursorToStringConverter(new CursorToStringConverter() {
    @Override
    public String convertToString(Cursor cursor) {
        //return cursor.getString(1);
        final int colIndex = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(Socio.C_NOME);
        return cursor.getString(colIndex);
    }
});

adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
    @Override
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint){
        return getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
                Socio.ALL_COLUMNS,
                Socio.C_NOME + " like '%"+constraint+"%'",
                null,
                Socio.C_NOME +" ASC");
    }
});  

filterListener = new TextWatcher() {
    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {
        if ("".equals(s))
            adapter.getFilter().filter(null);
        else
            adapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());   
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence arg0, int arg1, int arg2, int arg3) {}

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {}
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be trying to do too much... Here are a couple simplifications:

- I don't see where you are using the TextWatcher, but it is not
  required. In fact it might prevent the AutoCompleteTextView from
  working. So you should remove this.
- In your FilterQueryProvider and getAllSocios(), you should only ask
  for the columns `_id` and `Socio.C_NOME` since theses are the only
  two columns you use.
- Simply use `setStringConversionColumn()` instead of a
  CursorToStringConverter:

All together you only need:

```
cursor = socioData.getAllSocios();
adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
        this,
        android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line,
        cursor,
        new String[]{Socio.C_NOME},
        new int[]{android.R.id.text1} );

adapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
    @Override
    public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint){
        // Stop the FQP from looking for nothing
        if(constraint == null)
            return null;

        return getContentResolver().query(Data.CONTENT_URI,
            new String[] {"_id", Socio.C_NOME},
            Socio.C_NOME + " like ?", 
            "'%"+constraint+"%'",
            Socio.C_NOME);
    }
});
adapter.setStringConversionColumn(cursor.getColumnIndex(Socio.C_NOME));

filterText = (AutoCompleteTextView)findViewById(R.id.search);
filterText.setThreshold(1);
filterText.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Hope that helps!